# How to use deployed QVTo Eclipse Plug-In

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, qvt

I'm currently working on a QVTo transformation which transforms from an EMF model to a UML model. QVTo transformation works fine as it is if I run transformation from Eclipse Run Configurations as an Operational QVT Interpreter.

But now, I need it to be run programmatically from a Java Project which will handle when it must be run.

I have seen that QVTo projects can be started as Eclipse Plug-In projects and they can be deployed as Eclipse Plug-Ins, but my question is, how can I run QVTo transformations exported as Eclipse Plug-Ins within Java? If it is not possible as a Java solution, how could I run these transformations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See org.eclipse.m2m.qvt.oml.TransformationExecutor

You can see my MWE2 wrapper for QVTo at

http://git.eclipse.org/c/ocl/org.eclipse.ocl.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.ocl.examples.build/src/org/eclipse/ocl/examples/build/utilities/QVToTransformationExecutor.java

Regards

Ed Willink

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I already defined the implementation using my own  TransformationExecutor class implementation, as original one didn't have any functionality to return the traces of the executed transformations, I mark it as valid as I run into this solution already. Thanks.